# Upload all file from directory in solr

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

I just tried to upload all files from a directory to solr server.
My directory contains two **txt** files.

I use post tool to do this as :

**bin/post -c gettingStarted /any/linux/directory/**

My solr running in cloud mode on 8083 port but upper post command always looking for default 8983 port result connection failure.

I also used -p with same command for port but still problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bin/post -c gettingStarted -p 8083 /any/linux/directory/
```

or

```
bin/post -c gettingStarted -port 8083 /any/linux/directory/
```